# Is there a way to set the text in the text view to invisible?

Tags: android

I can't change its color or use alpha because the background may change and I won't know its color! 
Is there any other way to set it to invisible ? 
Also I don't want to set the text view invisible since I want the background to be visible!

Comment: set a tag... which is String...

Comment: hiding only text not textview ??

Comment: Put it in the same color than the background!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution and if it may help you can set the text in the text-view to an empty String.

Answer (score 5):

You can set a textview to INVISIBLE:

```
myTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

That way the textview will still be present but not seen

Answer (score 1):

Something like this..

```
String text = "Invisible Text";

TextView text1 = new TextView();
text1.setTag(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

why not,  set text value as empty string when you want to make it invisible. keep backup of the original value so that you can use it later when required.